# Mac Yosemite: Remove all space characters on lines that are starting with 0 (zero), in a standard text file

Tags: text, formatting, osx-yosemite

I have a text files, which is text copied from a subtitle file, that looks like this:

```
1 
00 : 00 : 02 , 240 --> 00 : 00 : 04 , 240 
(tadashi) <watashi no namae wa kanzaki jika. 

2 
00 : 00 : 04 , 240 --> 00 : 00 : 06 , 240 
makikomare te shimatta watashi wa 
tsuini? 

...
```

it goes on for some ~300 more chunks like this.

How would I make it look like this, without doing it manually :)  :

```
1 
00:00:02,240 --> 00:00:04,240 
(tadashi) <watashi no namae wa kanzaki jika. 

2 
00:00:04,240 --> 00:00:06,240 
makikomare te shimatta watashi wa 
tsuini? 

...
```

Basically, I would like to remove all spaces on lines that are starting with the number zero, except those spaces that are before and after the "arrow"

I am on OSX Yosemite but, if the only solution would be on some other os, I'd be glad to hear it regardless

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has answered you yet, here is a solution in python. You need to replace source and target filenames with what is appropriate for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re # this is the regex library

f = open('source.txt', 'rt') # this is the name of your source file
fnew = open('target.txt', 'wt') # this is the name of your target file

for line in f:
    new = re.sub(r'(\d\d) ([:|,]) (\d\d)', "\\1\\2\\3", line) 
    fnew.write(new)

f.close()
fnew.close()
```